# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance'

Tags: python, binance, modulenotfounderror, binance-api-client

I ran pip install python-binance.

`from binance.client import Client`
and get the error
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance**

I have renamed the binance.py file because some people have said that solved it for them but still getting the error?
Tried a bunch of other things like uninstall and reinstall

Comment: Could you add information about how you installed binance?

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and `pip` installs module for one Python but you run code with other Python. If you run code using `python script.py` then you can use `python -m pip install ...` to install modules for this Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem.
In the python interpreter I had the wrong package. I had 'binance' which I removed and added 'python-binance' package